# BehaviorSubject behavoir from an IObservable

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I wish to get the same behaviour that you would get from a `BehaviorSubject` from an `IObservable`.

When I do a `.Take(1)` I wish for it to return the "default value" until the underlying `IObservable` changes it. The underlying `IObservable` "pumps" once and completes.

I do not wish to actually use a `BehaviorSubject` (it would make this trivial) as I believe this is bad form.

Is this possible?

Comment: If a `BehaviorSubject` does exactly what you want, why is it bad form? It can be exposed as an `IObservable` if you want.

Comment: @MatthewFinlay - its just personal opinion, but to subscribe to an `IObservable` only to pump onto a `Subject` in the `.Subscribe` method doesn't really fit the RX paradigm of chaining `IObservable`s together. `Subject`s should only be at the very beginning of your RX chain IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a stream that will always have an initial value you might want to use `.StartWith()` method.

Under the hood this will do something very similar to Lee's answer except without the `.TakeUntil()`.

You might need to combine this with `.Replay(1)` if you want your subscribers to receive the last value immediately.

Comment: So the answer I went with was this: `observable.StartWith(defaultValue).Replay(1)`. For anyone looking, please note this will be HOT and therefore needs to be disposed appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IObservable<T> Behaviour<T>(IObservable<T> source)
{
    return Observable.Return(default(T)).TakeUntil(source).Concat(source);
}
```

Comment: This will not behave exactly like a `BehaviorSubject` if it's a hot observable and someone subscribes after the source has started. They will not get a value immediately, whereas a `BehaviorSubject` will return the most recent value straight away.